# Тире или запятая и тире в предложении с выводом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение

*Бóльшая часть жизни родителей приходится на советское время, сейчас они нечасто сталкиваются с вопросами трудоустройства(,) — вряд ли они в курсе современных реалий, так что кроме советов «хорошо учись» и «получай опыт работы» они мало что тебе подскажут.*

Во втором блоке предложения делается вывод на основании первый двух предложений. Я считаю, нужно поставить запятую, что показать, что вывод относится к обоим предложениям, а не только но второму. Верно? Или всё же это излишне — и так понятно, что делается общий вывод на основании сказанного ранее?

Answer (score 1):

**После редактирования:**

Бóльшую часть жизни родители прожили в советское время,  сейчас  с вопросами трудоустройства   сталкиваются не часто,  —  так что  вряд ли они  в курсе современных реалий и мало что тебе подскажут, кроме советов «хорошо учись» и «получай опыт работы».

**Пояснение.**

То же содержание можно выразить  короче (принцип информативности текста).

Деление на смысловые блоки  желательно изменить по принципу "описание ситуации — вывод из нее".

**Запятая и тире как единый знак ставится между смысловыми блоками.** Если поставить только запятую, то не будет увеличенной паузы, разделяющей смысловые блоки.

Comment: В таком варианте предложение читается нормально (в отличие от оригинала). Но есть вопрос: сталкиваются редко = нечасто? Почему у Вас раздельно?

Comment: В моём варианте тире обозначает то, что во втором блоке содержится вывод. Если вы ставите союз "так что", который обозначает, что дальше следует вывод, тире больше не требуется. Второй блок я бы оставил без правок.

Comment: @М_Г  Ряд наречий  "редко - часто" имеет градацию признака: редко - не редко и не часто - нередко (почти часто) - часто.

Comment: У Вас нечасто вообще отсутствует?

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь не подразумевается отрицание и лучше поставить «нечасто». Я в своём вопросе исправил.

Comment: Не часто - частотность 1252, нечасто - частотность 728. У этих вариантов разный смысл: нечасто - (почти) редко, не часто  - средний вариант. Поэтому здесь ничего не должно казаться: какой смысл вкладываете, такое слово/словосочетание и пишите.